# Change the df column names of named data frames

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a script that will loop through some data frames and change their column names to lowercase.

```
firmNames <- c("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5")
for(i in 1:length(firmNames)){
    fileName <- paste("data/",firmNames[i],".RData",sep="")
    load(fileName)
    upper <- names(get(firmNames[i]))
    lower <- tolower(upper)  # transforms to lower case
    names(get(firmNames[i])) <- lower  # This is the offending line
    save(get(firmNames[i]), file = fileName)
}
```

This causes a syntax error:

```
Error in names(get(firmNames[i])) <- lower : 
could not find function "get<-"
```

If I use `assign`, it still fails:

```
Error in save(get(firmNames[i]), file = fileName) : 
object ‘get(firmNames[i])’ not found
In addition: Warning message:
In assign(names(get(firmNames[i])), lower) :
only the first element is used as variable name
```

Strangely, printing `names(get(firmNames[i]))` displays perfectly, as does `lower`. They are both of mode character. What am I missing?

Comment: Keeping them as separate variables is a headache, for exactly this reason. I would prefer to `rbind` them all into a single dataframe, and then simply use `firmNames` as another ID variable. Then you are all set up to use plyr/ggplot2, and you can always slice out a single firm if you need to with `subset`.

Comment: Thank you- that will probably make life easier later.

Comment: (FYI I have been keeping them separate because these are pretty big data.frames, and I never actually wanted to analyze firms together for any reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward, readable, and sanity-preserving solution is to assign the `data.frame` you want to modify to a temporary object (here named `X`). Work on that, and when you've got it in shape, overwrite the original object with the correctly modified one:

```
# SETUP
firmNames <- c("file1","file2","file3","file4","file5")
file1 <- data.frame(ALLIGATOR=1:4, BLUEBIRD=rnorm(4))

file1
#   ALLIGATOR    BLUEBIRD
# 1         1 -0.37122263
# 2         2 -0.13939213
# 3         3 -0.79044157
# 4         4 -0.06837244


# MODIFY COLUMN NAMES
for (i in 1) {
    X <- get(firmNames[i])
    names(X) <- tolower(names(X))
    assign(firmNames[i], X)
}

file1
#   alligator    bluebird
# 1         1 -0.37122263
# 2         2 -0.13939213
# 3         3 -0.79044157
# 4         4 -0.06837244
```

Comment: Thank you- that answers the problem of assigning column names. How would you save the file? The line of assign(firmNames[i],X) doesn't seem to work- firmNames[i] prints out "file1."   When I try to save firmNames[i] I get an object not found.

Comment: That should work just fine.  `assign()` *expects* its first argument to be a variable name *given as a character string*. (Try something like this to see that that works:  `assign("MY_NAME", "Bernardo"); MY_NAME` to see that that is so.  Likewise, `save()` can take the names of objects to be saved as character strings.

Comment: That works- and your code works perfectly. But when I add save(firmNames[i], file="file.RData") to the loop, I get an object not found error.

Comment: OK -- I see the problem with trying to save that.  Because `save()` takes either character strings *or* symbols, it's trying to interpret `firmNames[i]`, and isn't finding an object of that very odd name. This should get the job done for you: `do.call(save, list(firmNames[1], file=fileName))`

Comment: YES! Thank you so much Josh. I'll be looking up this do.call function now!

Comment: (Is there a straightforward explanation as to why do.call works and just save doesn't?)

Comment: The key bit is that the arguments are (by default) evaluated during the construction of the call.  So `firmNames[1]` is 'turned into' the text string `"file1"` while the call is being put together, and **before it is evaluated**. By the time evaluation takes place, it is in the form we need it to be (`"file1"`).  Have a look at this related use of `call()`, and see if it helps you understand. `j <- "file1"; call("save", j, "file1.Rdata")`.  (You could then wrap that second statement in an `eval()` to evaluate it. `do.call()` does both steps, 1st constructing and then evaluating a call.)